# BizTalk Service Authorization

Tags: wcf, authentication, biztalk

I'm trying to implement authorization as Seroter described [here](http://seroter.wordpress.com/biztalk-and-wcf-part-vi-publishing-advanced-service-patterns/) (Service Authorization section). I've GAC'ed the library, changed `machine.config` and able to pick the custom behavior in *Select Behavior Extension* dialog. But I can't set the 'WindowsGroup' value, it gives me "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" and I can't figure why. Did anybody implement service authorization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved this problem.

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.ServiceModel.Configuration;

namespace Esb.Service.Authorization
{
    public class EsbBehaviorElement : BehaviorExtensionElement
    {
        private const string _windowsgroupIndexName = "windowsgroup";

        public EsbBehaviorElement()
        {
            if (!base.Properties.Contains(_windowsgroupIndexName))
            {
                base.Properties.Add(new ConfigurationProperty(_windowsgroupIndexName, typeof(string)));
            }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("WindowsGroup", IsRequired = false, DefaultValue = "")]
        public string WindowsGroup
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)base[_windowsgroupIndexName];
            }
            set
            {
                base[_windowsgroupIndexName] = value;
            }
        }

        public override Type BehaviorType
        {
            get
            {
                return typeof(EsbServiceBehavior);
            }
        }

        protected override object CreateBehavior()
        {
            return new EsbServiceBehavior(WindowsGroup);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know why Seroter's solution works without ctor where one should add "windowsgroup" property to the base collection of properties.